# ImageView partially on top of a layout

Tags: android

I am trying to put a `ImageView` partially on top of a `CardView`. 
I want the `ImageView` elevated on top of the `CardView`. I have attempted the following but I am not able to achieve the desired results.
Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.org.CarouselLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/root_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/profileCard"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
            app:cardElevation="4dp"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="false" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="24dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Hello Hello Hello"
                    android:textColor="#727272"
                    android:textSize="24sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="World World World"
                    android:textColor="#727272"
                    android:textSize="32sp" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/userImageProfile"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:elevation="8dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</com.org.CarouselLayout>
```

This is what I get:

[image]

I want the CircleImageView to be partially on top of the cardview something like below:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CoordinatorLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout`

Use this code

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"       
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/profileCard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        app:cardElevation="4dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="false" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="24dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hello Hello Hello"
                android:textColor="#727272"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="World World World"
                android:textColor="#727272"
                android:textSize="32sp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/userImageProfile"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/profileCard"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/profileCard"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="center|top" />
```

app:layout_anchor will be your card view id.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep your cardview and image in the framelayout and give the margins to image as needed to adjust for  you.
I hope it will help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/root_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/profileCard"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
            app:cardElevation="4dp"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="false" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="24dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Hello Hello Hello"
                    android:textColor="#727272"
                    android:textSize="24sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="World World World"
                    android:textColor="#727272"
                    android:textSize="32sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/userImageProfile"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:elevation="8dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    </FrameLayout>

</ScrollView>
```